# How to set the id on detached Hibernate proxy without LazyInitializationException?

Tags: hibernate, proxy, set, lazy-initialization

I'm using the object, which has over 15 related entities (parents). In my UI side I need only the ids of these entities, so I don't need Hibernate's **fetch** functionality and I use the **lazy proxy** concept to avoid the hit to database on the one hand and to have the objects with populated ids on the other.

To achieve this I have to use property acces instead of field access for all parent entities:

```
@Id
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) // this helps to avoid database hit on get, but not on set!!!    
private Long id;
```

So far so good, I load the object from database (no extra joins are made) and show it on the web UI with all relations (simple select inputs at most). I don't create clones (value objects) for UI, I use the detached hibernate objects directly. But when I do any changes to UI (change the parent object) the framework calls **setId()** for related proxy entities and .... this results in initialization of these proxies! Here is the code from Hibernate BasicLazyInitializer which does this:

```
else if ( method.equals(setIdentifierMethod) ) {
        initialize(); // Here the db hit occurs!!
        setIdentifier( (Serializable) args[0] );
        return INVOKE_IMPLEMENTATION;
     }
```

and the LazyInitializationException occurs (sure, I have no session at this point of time!).

So, is there any approach to do this without creation of value objects for all entities, fetched from database? I can say, that I always used data objects in UI directly, but they all were fetched completely (not proxies) and I haven't had such problems as now with these proxies...

I really don't understand, why Hibernate makes the proxy initialization on setting (though doesn't do on getting) the @ID field...

Thanks in advance!